# How to get reproducible Python Apache Beam Dataflow environment builds?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently I build our Google Dataflow Python environment using the official example setup.py: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py

The problems with this approach are:

1. OS compatibility issues I am developing on a Mac and Dataflow instances are based on Ubuntu. Using setup.py is quite painful here as it doesn't seem like the right tool to encampsualte.
2. DataflowRunner take about 20-25 minutes to identify

I think getting a docker image to mirror the Dataflow environment would be a good solution to these problems and running the DirectRunner on the image.

It seems to me templates https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/overview could help executing from different environments though I don't think they provide enough insight into the build process.

I am not sure where to find a Docker image I could use for this or if there are any better ways to reproducibly build Dataflow Python environments?